# get data to index.js(modul.export)

Tags: node.js, module.exports

I am new in Node.js.

I'm trying to figure out how I can get values from file *auth.js* to index.js with `module.export`.

File *auth.js*:

```js
const request = require('request');
request.post(
    'http://192.167.1.118/api/v1/auth/request',
    {
        form: {
            application: 'car',
            user: 'car',
        },
    },
    (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
        //console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        //console.log(body);
    }
);
module.exports.request = request;
```

File *index.js*:

```js
const aaa = require('./auth');
console.log(aaa.request);
```

Comment: And ? Thats the correct way to export the request object, but not your response body. Where is the problem ?!

Comment: Please keep in mind request is being deprecated so you may be better off switching to another option for http calls.

https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score -1):

You may need to convert that callback based request into promise.

Make an individual function which returns promise of you api response.

**auth.js**

```js
const request = require('request');

const sendRequest = () =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        request.post(
            'http://192.167.1.118/api/v1/auth/request',
            {
                form: {
                    application: 'car',
                    user: 'car',
                },
            },
            (error, res, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(body);
            }
        )
    );

module.exports.request = sendRequest;
```

**index.js**

```js
const { request } = require('./auth');

request().then(body => {
    console.log(body);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error); // <- error
});
```

Comment: The request library has a promise based alternative if he wanted to go with that. I don't believe there's a need to wrap the call in a promise for what he's trying to do.

Comment: feel free to improve my answer @JoshKelly, i didnt know it has promise based alternative. But it's still obvious that he need to use promise to retrieve the data from other file.